# Show mysql records according to the rank given and order by

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a query i should show the records according to the rank position given along with price order and group by sitename

```
shopdetails

id | productid | productname | sitename | siteid | site_priority | price | color
1     555          xyz          a          1          0            10      blue  
2     555          xyz          b          12         1            50      blue  
3     555          xyz          a          1          0            12      red  
4     555          xyz          c          3          4            9       red
5     555          xyz          e          15         5            19      blue
6     555          xyz          e          15         5            21      red
7     555          xyz          b          12         1            42      red 
8     555          xyz          c          3          4            56      blue
```

Three conditions i have to do for getting expected output
Conditions

1. if site_priority !=0 then put that record in that position. Say Eg. if the site_priority = 5 . show that record in fifth position after grouping all the sitename
2. Show records price asc if site_priority = 0
3. group the records by sitename and sort them by price

Final Expected Output

```
id | productid | productname | sitename | siteid | site_priority | price | color
  7     555          xyz           b        12           1            42    red   
  2     555          xyz           b        12           1            50    blue

############ the above two records are kept in the First Position since site_priority = 1 and ordered by price asc    
Now check for site_priority 2 is there if not show site_priority = 0 by price asc  ,
Now 2nd records would be

  1     555          xyz          a          1          0            10      blue 
  3     555          xyz          a          1          0            12      blue 

 Now check for site_priority 3 is there if not check for site_priority 0 ,
 is not then make the priority one level minus .
 move site_priority 4 to 3 , 5 to 4 .

  4     555          xyz          c          3          4            9       red
  8     555          xyz          c          3          4            56      blue
  5     555          xyz          e          15         5            19      blue
  6     555          xyz          e          15         5            21      red
```

Is there any best way to do this complicated Query .

i tired doing like this but it is not coming as i expected.

```
select 
    productid,
    productname,
    sitename,
    site_priority,
    price,
    colorname,
    (select 
            count(*)
        from
            shopdetails b
        where
            productid = 1250 and b.site_priority > a.site_priority order by price asc)+1  as rnk
from
    shopdetails a
where
    productid = 1250
having site_priority > 0
order by rnk
```

Easy to understand my first condition

```
sitename | priority
a            1
b            2  
c            3
d            0  
e            0
f            0
g            0
h            0
i            5



outpt

a  1 ==> position 1
b  2 ==> position 2
c  3 ==> position 3
d  0 ==> position 4
i  5 ==> position 5
e  0 ==> position 6
f  0 ==> position 7
g  0 ==> position 8
h  0 ==> position 9
```

Comment: Something similar to this? ORDER BY site_priority ASC, sitename ASC, price ASC

Comment: i tried but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

This was an interesting one to solve. I'm not positive I understood you correctly but here's what I came up with (it's a little funky). It matches the output of your sample though.

```
SELECT * FROM test
ORDER BY CASE WHEN site_priority = 0 THEN (
    SELECT k.outp FROM (
        SELECT @rownum:= @rownum + 1 outp, t.site_priority outp2 FROM (
            SELECT DISTINCT site_priority FROM test ORDER BY site_priority ASC) t, 
            (SELECT @rownum := 0) r 
            WHERE t.site_priority != @rownum) k 
    WHERE k.outp != k.outp2 limit 1)
ELSE site_priority END, sitename, price;
```

Comment: What you have tried is really good. I tried this kind of method before posting my question here. what you have missed in your query is my 2nd point  and you forget to order by the site name `aa , cc , bb , dd , ee` bot the site names should be near by. not site names far by

Comment: I added sitename and price to the order statement, is that what you meant? Sorry, I'm not quite clear what you're looking for. 

As for decrementing the values (sorry I missed that the first time), check out how to do lag/lead with MySQL and use that to check the lead values for priorities greater than the results of k.outp and, where they're more than 1 more than the current row value, decrease by 1.

Comment: What i am saying now is , if suppose the site having priority 4 . that site is not in the 4th position after ordering the sitename . It is in the last. I am unable to post screen shot here. if i post u will be clear